# Setting up Multi server environment in Sql Server 2012 - Enlist Failed Error

Tags: database-administration, sql-server-2012

I am trying to Configure the Master target server / Multi server environment in Sql Server 2012.

I changed :

```
MSXENCryptChannnelOptions  # Changed from 2 to 0
AllowDownloadedJobsToMatchProxyName # changed from 0 to 1 on the target
```

When I run the wizard I am getting below error

```
MSX Enlist failed for Job Server 'MasterServerName'
   The enlist operation Failed
      (Reason:SQL Server Agent Error: Unable to connect to MSX
      'MasterServerName'(Microsoft Sql Server, Error : 22026)
```

They both servers SQL Agents are running on the same windows service account.

**Adding the Log:**

```
Enlist TSX Progress
Create MSXOperator (Success) Checking for an existing MSXOperator.
Updating existing MSXOperator.
Successfully updated MSXOperator.
Make sure the Agent service for 'Test3' is running (Success)
    The service 'SQLSERVERAGENT' is running.
Ensure the agent startup account for 'Test4' has rights to login
    as a target server (Success)
Checking to see if the startup account for 'Test4' already exists.
Login exists on server.
Checking to see if login has rights to msdb.
Login has rights to msdb.
Checking to see if user is a member of the TargetServersRole.
User is a member of the TargetServersRole.
Enlist 'Test4' into 'Test3' (Error)
Enlisting target server 'Test4' with master server 'Test3'.
Using new enlistment method.
```

Messages

```
MSX enlist failed for JobServer 'Test4'. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
    An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement
    or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

    The enlist operation failed (reason: SQLServerAgent Error:
    Unable to connect to MSX 'TEST3'.) (Microsoft SQL Server,
    Error: 22026)
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the Service Account of SQL Server agent on both master and Target and it worked.